# which rails4/ruby2 web/app server on unix for production ussage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, passenger, unicorn, thin, puma

If you were deploying a production rails 4/ruby 2 app on unix, what app/web server would you use and why?

I have been using apache/passenger for my rails 2 & 3 apps for years, no big problems, it generally works pretty well. We have had one app that kept restarting and leaked memory, but most have been fine.

This app may have a bit more bursty traffic and require a bit more concurrent usage.

Other options I have read about :
Thin,
Unicorn,
Puma

I do need to support HTTPS, but don't need to run any other apps on this server, so I don't need all the features of Apache.

So I would like to hear from folks that run production apps in think, unicorn, puma or others, or even the latest passenger (with apache or nginx) and see if they have opinion on reliability, security & performance of these servers.

Comment: Phusion Passenger is not a static thing. It's been constantly developed over the past few years. The Passenger you see today is a very different (and better) beast than the one from a few years ago. Take a look at [the Technology Preview blog posts at blog.phusion.nl](http://blog.phusion.nl/category/passenger/phusion-passenger-technology-previews/). Version 4, released just a little over half a year ago, was a major improvement over not just Passenger 3 but also over Unicorn. As for Puma, try reading [this comparison](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Puma-vs-Phusion-Passenger).

Answer (score 1):

I found this today, I think it does a pretty good job at articulating the pros/cons of the options I described above - https://www.engineyard.com/articles/rails-server